# Why am I getting the old input every time I run this program?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import "./App.css";
const App = () => {
  const [newtodo, useTodo] = useState("");
  const [list, useList] = useState([]);

  function data() {
    useList((v) => [...v, newtodo]);
    console.log(list);
  }
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Todo</h1>
      <input onChange={(e) => useTodo(e.target.value)} value={newtodo} />
      <button onClick={() => data()}>Add</button>
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```

It is ReactJ code written in Vite. When I give input 'one' my output is [''] and then I enter 'two' my output is ['','one']. Does anybody know why this happens?

Comment: React state updates are asynchronous.

Comment: What is your expected output, If you share that, that might be more helpful

Comment: how can i make react update state immediately ?